# Reverse routing / URL generation in Clojure?

Tags: url, clojure, routes

What are some good ways (libraries or code) to do both routing and URL generation in Clojure?

I looked at the Compojure source code, but saw no indication that its routing is meant to also serve for URL generation. What else is out there?

An answer that says "there is no such library" is actually very useful, if you back it up with evidence and/or experience.

The motivation for this question comes from the first section of the [Rails Routing Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html): "The Rails router recognizes URLs and dispatches them to a controller's action. It can also generate paths and URLs, avoiding the need to hardcode strings in your views."

Dear You: I know someone out there (maybe *you*?) wants to say, "don't worry about URL generation; just hardcode strings for your URL's". Yes, I know I *could* do that, but that does not constitute an answer to this question. :) This is *not* a question about the wisdom or pros and cons of combined routing and URL generation. It is about *how do you do it?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pedestal](http://pedestal.io/)'s service layer does both routing and URL generation; this functionality is described in the [Service Routing](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/guides/documentation/service-routing.md) section of Pedestal documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across [route-one](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/route-one) which looks like it does just this. It's a small library which is fully compatible with Compojure, and provides a way of defining routes which can be run in reverse.

From their documentation, you can define a route like this:

```
(defroute document "/documents/:document-id")
```

And a couple of helper functions will be generated:

```
(document-path :document-id "123")
;; => "/documents/123"

(with-base-url "https://myservice.com"
   (document-url :document-id "123"))
;; => "https://myservice.com/documents/123"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written a minimal replacement for compojure's routing macros that allows you to name routing patterns and generate urls for them. It's at https://github.com/joodie/clout-link

Answer (score 0):

Much later, but the Clojure ecosystem has moved quite a bit :

- pedestal [service-routing](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/guides/documentation/service-routing.md) does that (but requires buy-in for other things)
- [bidi](https://github.com/juxt/bidi) does only what you describe, and also has a nice comparison with other libraries.

Taken from the bidi README, here is a comparison (use the `Run code` button) :
(I did that to use HTML because stackoverflow markdown has no table support).

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Library</th>
<th>clj</th>
<th>cljs</th>
<th>Syntax</th>
<th>Isomorphic?</th>
<th>Self-contained?</th>
<th>Extensible?</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/weavejester/compojure">Compojure</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td>Macros</td>
<td></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/cgrand/moustache">Moustache</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td>Macros</td>
<td></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/clojurewerkz/route-one">RouteOne</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td>Macros</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://pedestal.io/">Pedestal</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/thatismatt/gudu">gudu</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/gf3/secretary">secretary</a></td>
<td></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>Macros</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/DomKM/silk">silk</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://github.com/Prismatic/fnhouse">fnhouse</a></td>
<td>✔</td>
<td></td>
<td>Macros</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>✔</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>bidi</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>Data</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
<td>✔</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```